# QGIS GPX to Area and Perimeter

Tags: area, gpx

For a test I'm looking to a way to get the added/extendet geometry columns ( Vector menu -> Geometry Tools -> Export/Add geometry columns) for a GPX file.
The function Export/Add geometry columns generate a new column for area and perimeter as I see it on all the help I can find online.
But how can I get to this succesful point with my GPX as an input source?

My goal is to take a GPX file (for example you run around a lake and track it with a GPS watch, then load the gpx file into QGIS) and calculate the perimeter of this file.

Maybe I struggle because the GPX has to be converted first into a valid polygon?

My attempts so far:

- load GPX into QGIS
- From all the GPX-Shapes, I will use the "track_points" and create a polygon with the Vector menu -> Points2One.
- With this created shapefile, I can use the above mentioned Export/Add geometry column function to add the area and perimeter column.
- Result: it works, I will get an output, but unfortunately a wrong number, the area is not correct as well as perimeter (way too low and I also don't know which unit it is)

Comment: GPX coordinates are in degrees latitide/longitude. Degrees and square degrees are not useful units for length and area measurements. Convert data into some suitable projected coordinate system first.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it with GK3 and it worked! wohoo!

Comment: @patrick Stahel, can you explain a little deeper the way you get the goal? expecially about what coordinate system you used.
Tks